# Expand X-Axis Area to Reduce Clutter Among Observations

Tags: sas

I have the following code which produces a bar graph; however, I have over 30 observations(names of providers) in the first_md_seen variable thus the graph's x axis is super cluttered.

Is there a way to expand the size of the graph area so I can clearly see every  observations within first_md_seen variable and add some space between each of the observations so they are discernible?

As you can see in my code I changed the display positioning of the observations to vertical, but this did not help much.

Thanks!

```
 proc sgplot data = day1; 
  vbar first_md_seen / response = median fillattrs=(color=lightblue) 
    dataskin=gloss datalabel
    categoryorder=respdesc nostatlabel;
    xaxis grid display=(nolabel)
    fitpolicy=rotate 
    valuesrotate=vertical;
   yaxis grid discreteorder=data display=(nolabel);
  run;
```

Comment: You didn't set the size of the graph at all, have you tried that in the ODS GRAPHICS statement first?

Comment: @reeza, thanks I have not. Would setting the ods graphics affect the the length of the x axis so each observation label is less cluttered? currently referencing this link...https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=n0yadqm4wsfapgn1hzekfvu1ex0g.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: It depends on the settings, if the graph is wider there's more room. You can also explicitly set the labels you need using a VALUES statement to control which markers are there if you have a lot. Another option is to label the bars at the top alternately with legend entries at the bottom to avoid space issues. Of course, that's more work.

Comment: Thanks, I have like 40 observations so I may just need to export the data and make the graph in excel.

Comment: You'll have the exact same problem though it's slightly easier to control the size of graphs in Excel. 40 isn't a lot of observations, I recommend switching to a HBAR though, it's a lot easier to visualize a chart with a long of categories in the long format.